# Bouygues (France) B528 4G Router

Tags: router

I have a Bouygues 4G internet router model Huawei B528 in France.

When setting up the router a year ago, I was able to log in to it using a web browser interface (FireFox) with an address 198.162.1.1 which is pretty standard stuff. The base of the router shows the user and password as admin (by default).

When originally logging in to the router it would ask for the user name and then password (by default admin in both cases). From there I was able to set static IP addresses/MAC combinations without any problem and to change the WiFi access code to something more meaningful and easy to remember.

I was considering the purchase of an external aerial for the router, and out of curiosity I was minded to check the installation routines which involve logging in to the router and checking the settings for changing from the internal aerial to an external one. However, I find that I am now unable to log in to the router as the web browser s/w has changed to the extent that it no longer asks for the user just a password and the default password "admin" no longer works. Installing the Smart Home s/w has no different effect either.

[image]

Clicking on Forgot Password merely shows a page suggesting a hard reset but the worry is that by resetting two things:

- I’ll loose all the current settings (but have printouts so can put them back)
- It still won’t work - leaving me in a worse position than I am now

Two possibilities to consider:

- Has the B296 been updated behind the scenes to IPV6 and how does this
  impact the device I am using to connect to the router (if this is
  using IPV4). I would have thought IPVn was backwardly compatible.
- I read somewhere on a forum that some things are happening with
  Bouygues from July 2020 making improvements on the network and this
  could be silently affecting other users of their equipment.

Has anyone encountered this situation before and has any sage advice on how to proceed? I rather suspect that not many people are aware of the issue since people generally "set it and forget it" and will only encounter an issue if the router falls over...

Comment: You may want to consider just contacting them and asking them how to log in to the device.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks for your response. Already in progress since 2 weeks. I think they are flummoxed as well hence the question here to a wider audience.

Comment: Did you ever try resetting the router?

Comment: @user1073075 Yes, eventually I did a hard reset and re-entered all the settings, since when it has worked perfectly. There was no explanation discovered as to why/how the issue arose.